# CORS on Firefox and potential help on chrom private local network access

Tags: google-chrome, flask, firefox, cors, private-network-access

I am currently using the FLASK developer HTTP server, and I am trying to build a local service (run on localhost) that serves files for a remote visualization website.

Here is the code for the python side

```
@app.route('/task/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'CONNECT', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE', 'PATCH'])
def static_file1(path):
    p = "./task/" + path
    return flask.send_file(p, conditional=True)
```

For safari, it just works like a charm.
[image]
As this screenshot indicates, flask development http server can serve files partially.

However, it didn't work for firefox for one request but not for the other.
[image]
And here are the headers for the first failed request
[image]
Successful request header
[image]
So I do believe the CORS header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is set correctly, otherwise the second request would fail.

Then what did I do incorrectly?

Second part:

It also doesn't work in Chrome, both requests failed, but I found the article below explaining new security features:

[https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/#:~:text=%23%20What%20is%20Private%20Network%20Access,to%20make%20private%20network%20requests](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/#:%7E:text=%23%20What%20is%20Private%20Network%20Access,to%20make%20private%20network%20requests).

But even with "Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network" set to "true" (See screenshot above), both requests still failed in chrome. And error msg:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:10981/task/a5c8616777d000499ff0cd5dbb02c957/datahub.json' from origin 'https://somepublic.website' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

Any suggestion would be helpful!
Thanks!

Update 1:
After enabling ad-hoc SSL context (unsigned certificate) on the flask side, and using https on both localhost and "the public website", and changing the "#allow-insecure-localhost" flag in chrome to true, it works in chrome now. But still doesn't in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If you check [the specification](https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/) you will see that it is a "Draft Community Group Report" and

> This specification was published by the Web Platform Incubator Community Group. It is not a W3C Standard nor is it on the W3C Standards Track.

The contribute list is made up entirely of people working for Google.

I can't find any mention of it in [Firefox's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&o7=substring&f10=CP&j2=OR&f3=product&f8=cf_crash_signature&o6=substring&o5=substring&o4=substring&f9=CP&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&v3=access-control-allow-private-network&v8=access-control-allow-private-network&f5=alias&o3=substring&f6=short_desc&o8=substring&f1=OP&f7=status_whiteboard&f2=OP&query_format=advanced&v4=access-control-allow-private-network&v6=access-control-allow-private-network&v5=access-control-allow-private-network&f4=component&v7=access-control-allow-private-network&short_desc=Private%20Network%20Access).

---

It looks like this is a highly experimental specification, which Firefox simple doesn't implement.

There doesn't appear to be any way to persuade Firefox to provide access from a secure, public Oritin to an insecure private origin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So private local network access control is only a google thing... I see. But why did one request from the public to local fail while the other successes?